# QtTest QBenchmark print all run times

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, benchmarking, qttest

I'm running benchmarks in my tests with the QBENCHMARK macro. I pass the `iterations n` and `-o myfile.csv,csv` flags to the executable. Unfortunately, Qt only gives you the average run-time, accumulative run-time and number of runs.

I'd like to have all the run-times, so that I can calculate the confidence intervals. Is there any way to make that happen?